# Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework, ionic2, ubuntu-16.04

I am on ubuntu 16 and trying to run ionic 2 app.

My JAVA_HOME looks like this:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

    echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/simran/Android/Sdk
```

`$PATH`:

echo $PATH

```
/home/simran/bin:/home/simran/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/tools:/platform-tools:/home/simran/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/simran/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/simran/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/simran/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/simran/Android/Sdk/tools
```

if I run ionic run android:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/simran/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/simran/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on 32-bit ubuntu, you should install platform-tools@23.0.1 and build-tools@23.0.1